# How to generate .py file for enterprise MIBs using mibdump.py

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, mib

I am trying to generate .py file for below MIB using mibdump.py:

```
mibdump.py --mib-source . --generate-mib-texts  --destination-format pysnmp COMBA-REPEATERS- 
RH7W22-v1.0.0.txt
```

It generates .py file with html header.

```
 cat COMBA-REPEATERS-RH7W22.py
 <html>
           <head>
            <script>
            var forwardingUrl = "/page/bouncy.php? 
            ........................
  </html>
```

Can anyone suggest the correct command here? Or help me identify what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's hardcoded to pull unknown mibs from snmplabs.com, and unfortunately that site is down.  That result is an html redirect from whoever owns the domain snmplabs.com.

There's some resources here on where to find mibs:  https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/376

Comment: I tried using mibsource as given in the above link - it still generates the html redirect file: /dev/deepti/mibs$ mibdump.py  --destination-directory . --mib-source . --mib-source https://web.archive.org/web/20200215074721/http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/ COMBA-REPEATERS-RH7W22-MIB   Can you please let me know the correct command?